# Factory object or Product object

Tags: design-patterns, object, factory

I am learning more about the factory design pattern and came across the following example from Microsoft (I recoded it in java). [Example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx)

Short version:

- An abstract Product class
- A Concrete Product class that extends Product
- An abstract Factory class
- A Concrete Factory class that extends Factory
- An Assembly class

  ```
  public class ProductAssembler {

  public void AssembleProduct(Factory factory)
  {
  Product p = factory.getProduct();
  //do something
  }
  }
  ```
- A client

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  Factory factory = new ConcreteFactory();
  new ProductAssembler().AssembleProduct(factory);
  }
  ```

Question:

- What is the purpose of creating a factory object in the main method instead of a product object, why don't they pass a product object to the assembleproduct method and change
  that method so it accepts products instead of factories?
- Is the assembly class also part of the 'client' or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assembleProduct()` in `ProductAssembler` doesn't want to deal with instantiating products. So it wants to delegate this to a Factory so that when newer kinds of products are introduced, the existing factory changes (or a new factory is added) but `ProductAssembler` doesn't need to change. Instead of instantiation, `assembleProduct()` calls `factory.getProduct()`.

As far as the Factory pattern is concerned, `ProductAssembler` is the client. But if you look at it from an application perspective, your `main()` is the client and hence doesn't deal with Product objects.